# Learning object oriented - classes

Tags: c#, oop, programming-languages

I am new to C# and I am working on classes. What is the best way to learn classes so that a person can understand it.

I do understand to get a class you go up to the bar and click on add new item and then selected class. You can name that class such as AddValue.cs so that way that is what your class is being called.

I am trying to understand this I am working with number like a calculator.
I made my class and it is called CalculateValue.cs. In this I need need to create 2 private variables, _num1 and _num2.

Which I wrote 
int _num1;
int _num2;
I wrote that under the class name. But my whole problem is I don't really know how to code for the class. I am trying to understand it but its not working. What are some ways that help you understand how to code using classes?

Comment: _What is the best way to learn classes..._ A BOOK

Comment: Well the book I have does not talk about classes.

Comment: You would probably first look in internet for base object oriented programming topics.

Comment: You should try to wrote some code in Pascal first.

Comment: Nowadays, it is more and more common to have more than one book.

Comment: We don't know how you learn best. Some people learn by doing, some people learn by reading, some people learn by watching others, some people learn by attending lectures, some people learn with tutors. We don't know what works best for you. Look back at your past and see under what circumstances you did or did not learn a topic well, and then you'll know what to look for when learning new things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the kind of question SO like you asking here to be honest taylor. And to be fair - a book probably is your best solution anyway. There must be hundreds of books out there (many free) that will acquaint you with principles of OOP. I'll have a look for a link to a few in a minute if I get a chance.

As a sort of attempt to answer your question - I feel like you've got two main issues here - you're not exactly familiar with OOP principles, and you're stuck on how to use the IDE (visual studio). In which case, I'd advise you buy a book which deals with teaching OOP principles for a particular language so that the use of the IDE is also covered. As you've mentioned C#, go for that one. C# for dummies or something?

Think of OOP almost as an approach to programming. It's, amongst many other things, a way of implementing encapsulation. It's important for us to be organised when developing, very organised, and encapsulation is a way of you also organising your code. I don't mean just for organisation purposes (i.e. to keep it all clean and tidy), but to tackle many other issues aswell.

What you've just done there (with your two int variables), is created two private properties of your class. Think of those almost as attributes to your class, just as height is to person, it's a property. Another type of member can be a method. A method DOES something. Say, for example, you wanted to add those two numbers together, you may have your two variables and a 3rd member (a  method) called Add(). This class you're talking about then is capable of storing two numbers, and capable of performing something you've called Add() (it may be to add the two numbers). I could go on about the basics of then creating and instance of your class and using it but I'd be here all day. And besides - there's a lot more to take into consideration. For example, you've created PRIVATE variables, these won't be accessible outside of the class, and depending on what you want to do with them (i.e. how/where you would like to access them) they may need some sort of public access modifier. There's loads to learn mate, get reading. It's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Start with an OOP tutorial

learn basic concepts of OOP

Inheritance, Polymorphism, Encapsulation, Data Abstraction etc.

Then try to code

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more of an issue with your understanding of OOP then with C#, which is really the job for a good book or at the very least a good tutorial series. If you don't like to learn by reading through books, have a look at the tutorials on classes, methods etc [here](http://homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html) and if you think you're starting to get it, pick up a good book that goes into detail.

To answer your question, I think of a class using the concept of a person. A person can do things (methods). These things they do might affect their thoughts (fields) or their opinions that they tell others (public properties and fields). You might expect to find the private fields such as 'what to have for dinner tonight', public properties like 'favorite foods' or a method like 'cook dinner'. I'm not to good with metaphors and such, but this seems to be what my thoughts land on when I try to explain the concepts of a class without going into languages.

But really, you need to pick up a good book and get into detail.
In addition, this isn't really in the scope of questions that SO likes to have asked, since there really isn't any definite answer we can give you.

Good luck, it can take an while to grasp this stuff, but it's definitely a satisfying and worth the effort. Once you get the ground stuff down, you can just keep branching out to anything that interests you.

Answer (score -1):

classes are some kind of "grouping functions" the main purpose is that you can put several functions / values to the same place.

For example a class "Calculator" would have all common function you would need when calculating.

for Example Add() or Substract()

Comment: You can't really teach some one `object oriented` with a short answer. It's a job for a book not for an "answer"

Comment: Thank you for explaining a little bit for me.

Comment: Classes are not an group of functions. Class without members is a bad class. Actually class should represent some object from the real world: car, string, tree, book and so on. Class should answer to the asked question "what is this?" and not on "what it does?".

Comment: Ok Alex as you say class would represent some object from the real word. So having a class name AddValue and then ask yourself what is this is what you are saying. Such as the AddValue class is a calculator that allows you to add two numbers from textbox. All I am doing is trying to learn ways to understand it better.

Comment: AddValue is a method name on your calculator and not a class. Calculator should be responsible to add values. So the addvalue is a wrong name for an class is just a name of an method.

Comment: Don't call the class "AddValue" for a start. You said it yourself - "AddValue class is a calculator". So why don't you call it "Calculator"! After all, a calculator IS a real world object.

Comment: Ok that does make more sense. So can you have more than 1 method? such as add number and add string?